# Is "knowledge point" idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, idiomatic-language

In [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-78139-4_12) some Chinese authors wrote that:

> in a discipline, the knowledge body can be divided into a series of **knowledge points**, so we proposed and designed a discipline oriented common knowledge ontology base (KOB) to organize and store all the **knowledge points** and their relations in a discipline.

The term seems like a Chinglish transliteration, and I cannot find any such usage elsewhere, so I wonder if the concept (in exactly the same scenario as above) is idiomatic? If not, what is it in English? Maybe an information unit or a knowledge unit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Knowledge points" seems to be a specialized academic term in the field of pedagogy. You can find additional usage if you restrict your search to papers from that field.

It's idiomatic, but it's technical jargon.

Answer (score 0):

I thought *knowledge unit* would be more idiomatic since I have found one paper by several American authors using it: [Discovering Bloom Taxonomic Relationships between Knowledge Units Using Semantic Graph Triangularity Mining](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7864237)